# Добавление шаблонного текста в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Можно ли как-то добавлять шаблоный текст в `<textarea>`?  Допустим будет кнопка на сайте(реализованная через `<a>` или `<input>`), по нажатию на которую в поле ввода текста добавится шаблонная строчка. Или все это лучше делать через `<div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id="myTextarea">
Какой-то текст, бла бла
</textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Жми</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Пример текста";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Пример](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp)

Comment: А можно это сделать без ущерба всему тексту? Т.е. просто в конце предложения добавить

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вам нужно:)

Comment: document.getElementById("myTextarea").value =  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value + "Пример текста";

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, именно так, спасибо

Comment: Или с помощью Jquery,`$('a').click(function(){
        var text = "text";
        $('#myTextarea').append(text);
  });​`